# How to build a mysql query that checks date and time being between two values?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I want to build a specific calendar feature.

As a basement I have the following MySQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `presence` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `frequence` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fulltime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with the following example data:

```sql
INSERT INTO `presence` (`id`, `eid`, `start`, `end`, `frequence`, `fulltime`) VALUES (1, 14, "2021-11-29 10:00:00", "2021-12-13 18:00:00", NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `presence` (`id`, `eid`, `start`, `end`, `frequence`, `fulltime`) VALUES (2, 14, "2021-11-29 10:00:00", "2021-12-13 18:00:00", 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO `presence` (`id`, `eid`, `start`, `end`, `frequence`, `fulltime`) VALUES (3, 14, "2021-11-29 10:00:00", "2021-12-13 18:00:00", 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `presence` (`id`, `eid`, `start`, `end`, `frequence`, `fulltime`) VALUES (4, 14, "2021-11-29 10:00:00", "2021-12-13 18:00:00", NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO `presence` (`id`, `eid`, `start`, `end`, `frequence`, `fulltime`) VALUES (5, 14, "2021-11-29 10:00:00", NULL, 1, 1);
```

In my app environment I have the following examples:

**row id#1** means, that an employee (eid: 14) is present every day from 2021-11-29 to 2021-12-13. Each day from 10 am to 6 pm.

**row id#2** means, that an employee (eid: 14) is present every **monday** from 2021-11-29 to 2021-12-13. Each Monday from 10 am to 6 pm. Monday because `start` is a Monday and because `frequence = 1`.

**row id#3** means, that an employee (eid: 14) is present every **monday** from 2021-11-29 to 2021-12-13. Each Monday the entire day, because `fullday = 1`. Thus, ignoring the time.

**row id#4** means, that an employee (eid: 14) is present every day from 2021-11-29 to 2021-12-13. Each day the entire day, because `fullday = 1` tells again to ignore the time.

**row id#5** finally has an open end for the presence. It means the employee is present every Monday from 2021-11-29 until infinity.

I am working on the following query the entire day and I'm at stage where I can't tell what I expect anymore...

```sql
SET @date = "2021-12-13 19:00:00";
SET @fullday = 0;


SELECT start, end, frequence, fulltime
FROM `presence`
WHERE (
    IF (@fullday = 1, 
        DATE(@date) >= DATE(`start`)
        ,
        DATE(@date) >= DATE(`start`) AND
        TIME(@date) >= TIME(`start`)
    )
)
AND (
    IF (@fullday = 1, 
        DATE(@date) >= DATE(`end`)
        ,
        DATE(@date) >= DATE(`end`) AND
        TIME(@date) >= TIME(`end`)
    )
)
AND (
    `frequence` IS NULL OR
    `frequence` = 1 AND WEEKDAY(@date) = WEEKDAY(`start`)
)
```

In my app I will have a php function `employee_is_present(int $eid, string $date): bool` where `$date` can be either `Y-m-d H:i:s` or just `Y-m-d`, to check if an employee is generally available on a day (not having a time) or at a Very specific time. This is what I try to mimic using `SET @fullday = 0|1;`

Comment: you build a function which ,makes a sequence of all dates with the hiur so that you have a temporary table with all working hours row for row and the you check if a specific dates is in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the input, `date` could be either with or without time, it is easier to separate these two situations.
We can do that since we are using function call to query

Checking date only could use this query

```
SET @eid =14; 
SET @date = DATE("2021-12-13");
SELECT *
FROM presence
WHERE @date >= DATE(`start`) AND ( `end` IS NULL OR @date <= DATE(`end`))
AND (`frequence` IS NULL OR (`frequence` = 1 AND WEEKDAY(`start`) = WEEKDAY(@date)))
AND eid = @eid
```

Checking with time, we use the above query result and filter the time

```
SET @eid =14; 
SET @date = DATE("2021-12-13 19:00:00");
SET @time = TIME(@date);
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM presence
  WHERE @date >= DATE(`start`) AND ( `end` IS NULL OR @date <= DATE(`end`))
  AND (`frequence` IS NULL OR (`frequence` = 1 AND WEEKDAY(`start`) = WEEKDAY(@date)))
  AND eid = @eid
) f
WHERE `fulltime` = 1 OR (TIME(`start`) <= @time AND @time <= TIME(`end`))
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3e207fed77e34a6b458e79764e382156

Comment: I added a `DATE()` to your first query. Now it is working (before it excluded the start date). But your 2nd query gives me zero results

Comment: @John Doener, yes , thanks to point out the error.

Comment: I mean, the given date and time 2021-12-13 19:00:00 should give zero results as 19:00:00 is greater than 18:00:00

Comment: @John Doener, in the question, *fullday = 1. Thus, ignoring the time.*, So I think rows with fullday = 1 are still applicable

Comment: @John Doener the second query also got the same DATE() problem, fixed.